# Node relationship with JS and the browser using NPM modules and browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, server, browserify

I am a new StackOverflow user and I am starting to learn the back-end side of programming.
I use mostly JS client-side so the back-end side has some things that I need to clarify.

I have a problem regarding Node and its connection with the browser, even using browserify.
I know that a browser isn't Node's environment but I need to use that because I need to learn the little details of it.
The problem is, even though I use browserify in order to bound the several npm modules, everytime I try to require MySQL or HTTP or Express, errors occur.
If I use require('http') and/or require('express') this error occurs: TypeError: http.ServerResponse is undefined;
If, instead, I use require('mysql') this error occurs: TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function

My questions are:
-How can I solve this?
-Those are errors relative to browserify or they would be the same without it, using an environment different from the browser?
I'll prefer not a straightforward solution but an explanation with the code if necessary.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Modules such as `mysql` need low-level network interface. `http` is an abstraction over that network interface. So you really need `net` module, which is not avaliable in browser environment at all.

Browserify is just a semi-nodejs envirionment. It mocks up *some* of modules it can polyfill in browser.

You should [install Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) run your programm as such

```sh
node your_script.js
```

Comment: So, if, for example, I want to create a database for a website using the browser as an interface, how can I do that? The fact is that I saw some projects out there and people actually didn't have a problem. Thank you

Comment: @RichardM. if you want to do that you should do backend which will communicate with db through its interface, and frontend which will communicate with backend through REST or GraphQL.

Backends provide simple program interfaces while frontends provides human interface for program interfaces.